# Firebase Cloud Message Not Receiving Notification

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am quite new to android development. I recently learn to use Firebase cloud message. I tested it worked before. Now it is not working. I want to know if it is why FCM is not working.

Last month, I published my app live with dependencies of

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
```

I have tested on several devices that the firebase console can successfully send notification to all devices.

And a week ago, I noticed there is 9.0.2 version but I did not publish my app with this new dependencies yet. Is it true that whenever a new version of firebase-messaging pushed out by google, it will make all the device running old dependencies not able to receive notification?

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: should add current code to the question though.

Comment: By *not working*, do you mean the devices don't receive any notification? Are you receiving any error from server when sending notifications?

Comment: no device receive notification

Comment: The new versions of the messaging library should not cause the previous versions to stop working. 9.0.0 should still work as expected. How did you confirm that the devices are not receiving? Also please include the request you are using to send the notifications and the response you are getting.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your console if it showing a message similar to

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires xxxxxxx but found yyyyyyy
```

Then you need to update your google services
As new version of Firebase is used by the App and the play services having an older version then it needs to get updated, or the device will not receive notifications and will show as not registered